# Using Given/Let w/ Feature/Scenario in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'd like to set a variable using "given" (or "let") that is accessible by all of the "features" within my spec.rb file. How do I do this? Where should the "given" statement be located within the file? Thanks!

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Home page" do
  given(:base_title) { "What Key Am I In?" }
  scenario "should have the content 'What Key Am I In?'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    expect(page).to have_content('What Key Am I In?')
  end

  scenario "should have the title 'What Key Am I In? | Home'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title}")
  end

  scenario "should not have a custom page title | Home'" do
    visit '/static_pages/home'
    expect(page).not_to have_title("| Home")
  end  
end

feature "About page" do
  scenario "should have the content 'About'" do
    visit '/static_pages/about'
    expect(page).to have_content('About')
  end

  scenario "should have the title 'What Key Am I In? | About'" do
    visit '/static_pages/about'
    expect(page).to have_title('What Key Am I In? | About')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`given/let` calls are used at the top of a `feature/describe/context` block and apply to all contained `feature/describe/context` or `scenario/it` blocks. In your case, if you have two separate `feature` blocks, you'd want to enclose them in a higher level `feature/describe/context` block and place whatever `given/let` calls you want to apply to all at the higher level.

To quote the capybara documentation for use in RSpec:

> `feature` is in fact just an alias for `describe ..., :type =>
>   :feature`, `background` is an alias for `before`, `scenario` for `it`,
>   and `given/given!` aliases for `let/let!`, respectively.

Further, in RSpec, `describe` blocks (whether expressed through `describe`, `context` or the Capybara alias `feature`) can be nested arbitrarily deeply.  In Cucumber, by contrast, `feature` can only exist at the top level of the spec.

You can Google "rspec nested describe" for more info.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I've added some code to help clarify my question. I am using "given(:base_title) { "What Key Am I In?" }" within the first feature block, but the :base_title variable is not usable in the other feature blocks, but when I move it up to the top, I get an error. Is it possible to set a variable that is usable in the whole file? Thanks again

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. Is there any difference between using feature vs using describe?

Comment: The following is from the Capybara README on github: `feature` is in fact just an alias for `describe ..., :type => :feature`, `background` is an alias for `before`, `scenario` for `it`, and `given/given!` aliases for `let/let!`, respectively.

Comment: Is there anything else you're looking for in the way of an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `context` within `feature` to solve your problem.

```
feature 'Static page' do
  given(:base_title) { "What Key Am I In?" }

  context 'Home page' do
    # code
  end

  context 'About page' do
    # code
  end
end
```

Two side notes:

1. It's not nice to put two feature blocks in one file
2. There is no alias for `context` in Capybara DSL, you can use it directly.

Comment: In fact, you can replace `feature` with `describe` in the above and replace `context` with `feature`, along with several other alternatives, given that `context` is an RSpec alias for `describe` and `feature` is the Capybara equivalent to `describe, type: :feature`, right?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, the reason to use such DSL is to mimic Cucumber's ATDD syntax, and "context" is also a valid word there. It will make little sense to make it more complicated.

Comment: It's not clear why the OP would want to be Cucumber-like in the context of RSpec, but assuming that s/he does, it's not clear why your proposal is more Cucumber-like or less-complicated than the alternative of adding a `describe` or `context` at the outer level and leaving his "feature" syntax alone vs. your approach of changing his `feature`s to `context`s and adding a `feature` at the outer level.  Further, in Cucumber, `given`, `when` and `then` only exist under a `Background` or `Scenario`, which is not the the case here with either approach.